# Подскажите библиотеку для создания скролла как будто по слайдам

Tags: javascript, html, css, поиск-библиотек

Нужна библиотека которая по скроллу переводит человека как бы на другой слайд. Часто вижу такой переход в лендингах.

Comment: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/responsive.html#firstPage

Comment: Привет, попробуй воспользоваться фреймворком bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: @soledar10 киньте в ответы чтобы я мог отметить как правильный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/responsive.html#secondPage

Пример

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
});
```

```css
.section {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide">Two 1</div>
        <div class="slide">Two 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Three</div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```